# Having issue with Google Analytics Android V4

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

I have implemented Play Service version

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'
```

And in my app.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the end of the app.gradle.

When I run the application I can see:

```
Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
```

But when I try to see it in Google Analytics page, in Real time > Overview. Nothing is displayed there. GCM works fine but, I have been trying to implement google analytics from a week; everything works fine but I can not see it being reflected in website. I am just trying to get the screenview.

I have tried with play service 3.0.0 and analytics version 9.0.0 also, but no result.

I am using Android studio 2.1 with Gradle

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

and I also turned off my Instant Run. Still same result. I tried to wait for more than a day, in hope that it takes time. But nothing happened.

My Code for Tracker initialisations:

```
public synchronized com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker getGATracker() {
    if (mGATracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setDryRun(false); // to test 

        mGATracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mGATracker;
}
```

Method to call screenView:

```
public static void screenView(Activity activity, String screeName) {
    App app = (App) activity.getApplication();
    Tracker mTracker = app.getGATracker();

    if (mTracker != null) {
        mTracker.setScreenName(screeName);
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    }

}
```

Logs in LogCat:

```
D/GAv4: Hit delivery requested: ht=1464600050117, _s=5, _v=ma8.4.87, a=1877192790, aid=<my package name>, an=<app name>, av=0.0.44, cid=5f30d24d-1cfa-496e-9d94-9223fd9c72ef, sd=redeem, sr=1080x1794, t=screenview, tid=<my app Id UA-xxxxxxxx-1>, ul=en-us, v=1

D/GAv4: Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
```

Comment: Did you add xml config file to the project with the view id of your Analytics panel?

Comment: @fillobotto Yes I did, I can see my ID in log. But still nothing happens. Even I called setDryRun to false.

Comment: But in the code you posted I can't see where you are setting Tracker's config file

Comment: @fillobotto It's being provided by the google-services.json file that we create when enabling the Google Analytics. https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Comment: Is the app running on a physical device, emulator, or both?

Comment: Sorry, all. I fixed the issue. It works in emulator as well. To admit my mistake, i was calling tracker.setColor*** method instead of tracker.setScreenName("SomeName"); That was my typo and also poor documentation as well as CTRL + SPACE thing.

Why the hell, google put setcolor method in analytics? I wonder....